# Incorrect parameter when using IsNull in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I've been trying to use the `IsNull()` function to ensure that there is a value for a field.

```
SELECT crawled.id,
       IsNull(sranking.score,0) as Score,
       crawled.url,
       crawled.title,
       crawled.blurb
FROM crawled
    LEFT JOIN sranking ON crawled.id = sranking.sid
WHERE crawled.body LIKE '%".$term."%'
ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $c
```

But I get the error message:

> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'IsNull'

Anybody have any ideas? I'm pretty new to MySQL.

Answer (score 11):

[ISNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) tests if the passed expression is NULL. What you need is [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), or COALESCE, as `xyld` has mentioned.

```
SELECT crawled.id, IFNULL(sranking.score, 0) as Score, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using `coalesce`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

It returns the first non-null value.